# AMCharts4 XYChart no prezoom when hiding a series

Tags: amcharts4

I have an AMCharts XYChart with one columnseries which is added and shown when I init the chart. I have another lineseries which I also add, but series.hide() when I init the chart. The legend then allows me to show/hide the lineseries.

Two problems:

1) When the chart is first set up, it prezooms to the single columnseries. I want the ability to zoom on the chart, but I don't want it to prezoom when it first loads with the single series. What is the chart configuration to disable this or return the chart to the full zoom extent onready (which would be a bit hacky).

2) The second issue is that sometimes when I click the lineseries in the legend to add it, the zoom doesn't work at first when the lineseries is added to the chart. Instead, it may only correctly zoom on the subsequent click. I may escape this second problem if the first one is fixed.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`keepSelection`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#keepSelection_property) to true on your axes? If that doesn't help, please post a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks.